# How to add a cron job entry using Chef recipe

Tags: shell, cron, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

All,

I have a shell script that is creates tar file of logs. I have embeded the recipe in the cookbook.

The recipe looks like this :

```
cookbook_file "/var/create-tar.sh" do
source "create-tar.sh"
mode 0755
end

execute "create tar files of logs older than 1 day" do
command "sh /var/create-tar.sh"
end
```

The execute resource is executing the recipe. I want to schedule this shell script in cron by making an entry in cronjob.

The crontab entry should be :

```
*/2 * * * * sh -x /var/test.sh  > /var/log/backup 2>&1
```

How can I add this entry in my recipe?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Cron Jobs in Chef

Chef includes a resource for setting up Cron jobs - it's called [cron](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron.html).

```rb
cron 'test' do
  minute '*/2'
  command 'sh -x /var/test.sh  > /var/log/backup 2>&1'
end
```

But what is your ultimate goal? Log rotation?

### Log Rotation with Chef and Logrotate

There is a tool for that, called [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) and there is a Chef cookbook for that: [logrotate](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/logrotate).

This gives you a resource that allows to to specify, which logs you want to rotate and with what options:

```rb
logrotate_app 'test' do
  path      '/var/log/test/*.log'
  frequency 'daily'
  rotate    30
end
```

Just in case you want to implement such a thing ;-)

Comment: How can I test this using test kitchen ? Do I need to write the kitchen.yml file for this ?

Comment: How is that question related to the topic?